# Regex to parse nmea sentenes

Tags: regex

I need to parse nmea sentences with provided test cases, I managed to pass most but there are few wrong sentences which should not be matching but they are matching. I am not not very good at it so I am not able to get how to fix it. I will provide the test data and regex.

`regex = \$G([A-Z]{4}),(.*?)(\*[0-9A-Fa-f]{2})`

Here is the data:

```
BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(ValidOneField)
{
    BOOST_CHECK(isSingleSentence("$GPXXX,1*23"));
}

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(ValidTwoFields)
{
    BOOST_CHECK(isSingleSentence("$GPXXX,1,testing*69"));
}

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(ValidEmptyField)
{
    BOOST_CHECK(isSingleSentence("$GPXXX,*47"));
}

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(ValidManyFields)
{
    const std::string commas(1000, ','); // 1000 fields
    BOOST_CHECK(isSingleSentence("$GPXXX" + commas + "*28"));
}

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(ValidEdgeLetters)
{
    BOOST_CHECK(isSingleSentence("$GPAAA,1*23"));
    BOOST_CHECK(isSingleSentence("$GPZZZ,1*23"));
}

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(ValidEdgeHexDecimalDigits)
{
    BOOST_CHECK(isSingleSentence("$GPXXX,1*09"));
    BOOST_CHECK(isSingleSentence("$GPXXX,1*90"));
}

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(ValidLowercaseHexCharacters)
{
    BOOST_CHECK(isSingleSentence("$GPXXX,*ce"));
}

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(ValidUppercaseHexCharacters)
{
    BOOST_CHECK(isSingleSentence("$GPXXX,*DB"));
}

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(ValidHexCharactersMix)
{
    BOOST_CHECK(isSingleSentence("$GPXXX,*b6"));
    BOOST_CHECK(isSingleSentence("$GPXXX,*3E"));
    BOOST_CHECK(isSingleSentence("$GPXXX,*cD"));
}

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(ValidEdgeHexDigits)
{
    BOOST_CHECK(isSingleSentence("$GPXXX,*af"));
    BOOST_CHECK(isSingleSentence("$GPXXX,*FA"));
}

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(ValidTypicalSentences)
{
    BOOST_CHECK(isSingleSentence("$GPGLL,5425.31,N,107.03,W,82610*69"));
    BOOST_CHECK(isSingleSentence("$GPWPL,5128.62,N,00027.58,W,EGLL*59"));
    BOOST_CHECK(isSingleSentence("$GPRMC,113922.000,A,3722.5993,N,00559.2458,W,0.000,0.00,150914,,A*62"));
    BOOST_CHECK(isSingleSentence("$GPGGA,113922.000,3722.5993,N,00559.2458,W,1,0,,4.0,M,,M,,*40"));
    BOOST_CHECK(isSingleSentence("$GPMSS,55,27,318.0,100,*66"));
}

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(ValidTransmitterOtherThanGP)
{                                                 // GP: GPS
    BOOST_CHECK(isSingleSentence("$GLXXX,1*23")); // GL: GLONASS
    BOOST_CHECK(isSingleSentence("$GAXXX,1*23")); // GA: Galileo
    BOOST_CHECK(isSingleSentence("$GBXXX,1*23")); // GB: BeiDou
    BOOST_CHECK(isSingleSentence("$GIXXX,1*23")); // GA: NavIC
    BOOST_CHECK(isSingleSentence("$GQXXX,1*23")); // GB: QZSS
    BOOST_CHECK(isSingleSentence("$GNXXX,1*23")); // GN: combined
}

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(InvalidMissingSuffix)
{
    BOOST_CHECK(!isSingleSentence(""));
    BOOST_CHECK(!isSingleSentence("$"));
    BOOST_CHECK(!isSingleSentence("$G"));
    BOOST_CHECK(!isSingleSentence("$GP"));
    BOOST_CHECK(!isSingleSentence("$GPG"));
    BOOST_CHECK(!isSingleSentence("$GPGL"));
    BOOST_CHECK(!isSingleSentence("$GPGLL"));
    BOOST_CHECK(!isSingleSentence("$GPGLL,"));
    BOOST_CHECK(!isSingleSentence("$GPGLL,*"));
    BOOST_CHECK(!isSingleSentence("$GPGLL,*1"));
}

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(InvalidStartSymbol)
{
    BOOST_CHECK(!isSingleSentence("SGPXXX,*01"));
    BOOST_CHECK(!isSingleSentence("GPXXX,*01"));
}

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(InvalidLettersPrefix)
{
    BOOST_CHECK(!isSingleSentence("$HPXXX,*01"));
    BOOST_CHECK(!isSingleSentence("$PXXX,*01"));
    BOOST_CHECK(!isSingleSentence("$GXXX,*01"));
    BOOST_CHECK(!isSingleSentence("$KLXXX,*01"));
    BOOST_CHECK(!isSingleSentence("$XXX,*01"));
}

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(InvalidFormatCode)
{
    BOOST_CHECK(!isSingleSentence("$GP,*01"));
    BOOST_CHECK(!isSingleSentence("$GPX,*01"));
    BOOST_CHECK(!isSingleSentence("$GPXX,*01"));
    BOOST_CHECK(!isSingleSentence("$GP1XX,*01"));
    BOOST_CHECK(!isSingleSentence("$GPX%X,*01"));
    BOOST_CHECK(!isSingleSentence("$GPXX ,*01"));
    BOOST_CHECK(!isSingleSentence("$GPabc,*01"));
}

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(InvalidNoFields)
{
    BOOST_CHECK(!isSingleSentence("$GPXXX*01"));
}

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(InvalidReservedCharInField)
{
    BOOST_CHECK(!isSingleSentence("$GPXXX,$77*01"));
    BOOST_CHECK(!isSingleSentence("$GPXXX,2*3,1*77"));
}

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(InvalidChecksumPrefix)
{
    BOOST_CHECK(!isSingleSentence("$GPXX,X77"));
    BOOST_CHECK(!isSingleSentence("$GPXX,X%77"));
}

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(InvalidChecksumTooLong)
{
    BOOST_CHECK(!isSingleSentence("$GPXXX,*012"));
}

// There are some other ASCII symbols between the 0-9 characters and the A-Z range,
// and then some more between A-Z and the a-z range.
BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(InvalidHexSymbolsFromMiddleOfASCIIRange)
{
    BOOST_CHECK(!isSingleSentence("$GPXXX,*=3"));
    BOOST_CHECK(!isSingleSentence("$GPXXX,*4?"));
    BOOST_CHECK(!isSingleSentence("$GPXXX,*^5"));
    BOOST_CHECK(!isSingleSentence("$GPXXX,*8-"));
}

// ASCII symbols taken from the edges just outside the ASCII ranges of valid hex characters.
BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(InvalidHexSymbolsASCIIBoundaries)
{
    BOOST_CHECK(!isSingleSentence("$GPXXX,*2:"));
    BOOST_CHECK(!isSingleSentence("$GPXXX,*@9"));
    BOOST_CHECK(!isSingleSentence("$GPXXX,*7G"));
    BOOST_CHECK(!isSingleSentence("$GPXXX,*`8"));
    BOOST_CHECK(!isSingleSentence("$GPXXX,*1/"));
    BOOST_CHECK(!isSingleSentence("$GPXXX,*g3"));
}
```

For example:
These should not be matching

```
BOOST_CHECK(!isSingleSentence("$GPXXX,$77*01"));
BOOST_CHECK(!isSingleSentence("$GPXXX,2*3,1*77"));
BOOST_CHECK(!isSingleSentence("$GPXXX,*012"));
```

How to fix this regex to not match these?

Comment: Not sure about all the NMEA rules for validation, but this seems to check all your given samples? `"\$(G[ABILNPQ][A-Z]{3}(?:,(?:\d+(?:\.\d+)?|[a-zA-Z]+|))*,\w*\*[\dA-Fa-f]{2})"`, see an online [demo](https://regex101.com/r/VTj6Fj/1)

Comment: @Jvd it works, but there is one issue, if there are more than 2 characters at the end it should fail.

Comment: And does not match when there is a negative number.

Comment: I'm not understanding your 1st comment about the 2 characters, but I see you have solved your issue by yourself. That's nice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a bit of research I was able to make it work. Credit to @JvdV

```
(\$(G[ABILNPQ][A-Z]{3}(?:,(-?\d*(\.\d+)?(?:\.\d+)?|[a-zA-Z]+|))+\w*\*[\dA-Fa-f]{2})$)
```